# Changing page orientation last

Tags: html, css

So far I'm only managing to handle the first page, but my focus is the last, the last I want to be in landscape orientation.

I used it on the first page,

```
@page :first {
    size: A4 portrait;
}
@page {
    size: A4 landscape;
}
```

I tried the most obvious, like @ page: last but not available

is an example

http://jsfiddle.net/AFLPY/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware <strike>there's no way to control it</strike>.  (See edit below!!)

<strike>The spec only seem to offer `:first` without a `:last` counterpart.</strike>

References:

- http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-page/#at-page-rule
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page

**Edit:**

What about something like this example from the w3 spec?

> In this example, the two tables are rendered on landscape pages
>   (indeed, on the same page, if they fit). The page type "narrow" is
>   used for the
>
> after the second table, as the page properties for
>   the table element are no longer in effect:
>
> ```
> @page narrow { size: 9cm 18cm }
> @page rotated { size: landscape }
> div { page: narrow }
> table { page: rotated }
> ```
>
> with this document:
>
> ```
> <div>
> <table>...</table>
> <table>...</table>
> <p>This text is rendered on a 'narrow' page</p>
> </div>
> ```

So, if you set an #id for the last element on the last page, you could perhaps style it that way?